# HTML form- check boxes programmatically

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am working on a Google Add-On in Google Apps Script, and I am attempting to make an HTML Form as a sidebar, the code of which is here:

```
<body onload="google.script.run.onSettingsOpen()">

<form id="baseSettings" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.processForm(this); google.script.host.close()">


  <h2>What settings would you like to be on? Please select all that apply.</h2>
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="spaces" id="spaces">Double spaces
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="punctuation" id="punctuation">Punctuation outside of quotes
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="caps" id="caps">Capitilazation at beginning of sentences
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="contractions" id="contractions">Contractions
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="numbers" id="numbers">Small numbers
  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="repWords" id="repWords">Repeated words
  <br>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
```

I am attempting to use User Properties to keep track of which boxes should be checked for this form  (it is a settings panel). The user properties all start as true, and can be only true or false- no other values. I have written the following code to get the check boxes to reflect what has been previously selected by the user for their preferences:

```
function onSettingsOpen()
{

  populateData ();
  initializePreferences();

  document.getElementById(propsList[1]).checked = (allPreferences.getProperty(propsList[1]) === "true");
  document.getElementById(propsList[2]).checked = (allPreferences.getProperty(propsList[2]) === "true");
  document.getElementById(propsList[3]).checked = (allPreferences.getProperty(propsList[3]) === "true");
  document.getElementById(propsList[4]).checked = (allPreferences.getProperty(propsList[4]) === "true");
  document.getElementById(propsList[5]).checked = (allPreferences.getProperty(propsList[5]) === "true");

}
```

The propsList array is as follows:

```
var propsList = ["spaces", "punctuation", "caps", "contractions", "numbers", "repWords"];
```

Here is the processForm function:

```
function processForm(formObject)
{
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var results = JSON.stringify(formObject.checks);
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    if (allPreferences.getProperty(allPros[i]) === "false" && results.includes(allProps[i]))
    {
      allPreferences.setProperty(allProps[i], true)
    }
    else if (allPreferences.getProperty(allPros[i]) === "true" && !results.includes(allProps[i]))
    {
      allPreferences.setProperty(allProps[i], false)
    }
  }

}
```

And here is the populateData() function:

```
function populateData ()
{
  if (doc == undefined)
  {
    doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    bod = doc.getBody();
    docTxt = bod.getText();
    toEdit = bod.editAsText();
    paragraphs = bod.getParagraphs();
    ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    allPreferences = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  }
}
```

My current issue is that I am getting an error message reading: "Execution failed: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined." I'm not sure what to do about this. I have tried it in JQuery as well, to no avail. All I want to do is be able to access the "checked" attribute of my form and edit it programatically. Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Server side is server side and client side is client side and the only way to communicate between those two is `google.script.run`. Review documentation and familiarise yourself with server client communication.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. But is there a form event attribute (like onsubmit) that runs when the user opens the form (which I have in the form of a sidebar currently)? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I also tried using the onload attribute in the main body tag, which does not seem to have worked either.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work- thank you.

Comment: Sorry, new problem- I am now getting an error message saying "Execution failed: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined." What do I do about that? It is when I try to use document.getElementById().

Comment: [Edit] your question with the latest script and error.

Comment: Ok I did, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Show `onSettingsOpen()` function and  your code.gs file fully.

Comment: I put in onSettingsOpen() and two other functions. The Main.gs file is 350 lines long and not commented; it also uses a lot of information from other gs files. Is there anything in particular you need to see?

Comment: `onSettingsOpen()` should return the properties boolean as array/object to the client side. On client side, parse the array/object and check the checkboxes. You need to review and practice `google.script.run` more. Specifically note that it's a async function and you'll need to use success handler to receive the return data. Practice in a new  project file(html&.gs). `document` is defined client side and not the server side. `properties` are present on the server side. Keep an eye on what type you transfer, as not all types are not transferable from server to client.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll get cracking on this and let you know how it all pans out.